# $stateChangeSuccess, always the same value of $state.params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can't wrap my head around this, I'm really struggling with `ui-route`and `$stateChangeSuccess` and `$watch`, got two issues. I'm trying to change a value of a parameter, when I change the `state`, click a url. I think it's important to know that I use sub-states. With my current setup I get that the `$stateChangeSuccess` triggers twice on load, meaning it sets the value right away. What I'm trying to do is to only have it set on change of url.

My route looks like this, I'm trying to set the value of a parameter

```
.state('medications', {
                url: '/medications',
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'mainController',
                params: { showSection: false },
                resolve: {
                    postPromise: ['medicationservice', function(medicationservice) {
                        return medicationservice.getAll();
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('medications.add', {
                url: '/add',
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'mainController',
                params: { showSection: true },
            })
```

in my controller I got the following, where I set the `openSesame` parameter to `false` explicitly on `init`, but as described it triggers and sets it to `true`.

```
mainModule.controller('mainController', [
        '$scope',
        '$state',
        '$rootScope',
        'medicationservice',
        function($scope, $state, $rootScope, medicationservice) {
            $scope.medication = {};
            $scope.medications = medicationservice.posts;
            $scope.openSesame = false;

            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
                $scope.openSesame = true;
                console.log($scope.openSesame);
            });
}]);
```

[in my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZEvKONRoR46k3VLSlth5?p=preview) the state change works once, that is if I use the `$rootScope`.

Comment: You want to change `showSection` parameter on state change?

Comment: Yea, basically I want to use the `showSection` parameter to set  `$scope.openSesame` @inspired

Comment: ok loot at my updated answer and [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zQxIhI6GKmKBY1bn4WSf?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `$stateChangeSuccess` without `$injecting` `$rootScope`. You can set a listener on the `$scope` object instead. Take a look at the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zQxIhI6GKmKBY1bn4WSf?p=preview).

And the revised code:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
  app.controller('mainController', [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    function($scope, $state) {
      $scope.medication = {};
      $scope.openSesame = false;

      $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState){
        $scope.openSesame = toState.params.showSection;
      });

      $scope.triggerMe = function() {
        alert('yes');
      };
    }
  ]);

  app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('medications', {
          url: '/medications',
          template: '<div>{{openSesame}}</div>',
          controller: 'mainController',
          params: {
            showSection: false
          }
        })
        .state('medications.add', {
          url: '/add',
          template: '<div>{{openSesame}}</div>',
          controller: 'mainController',
          params: {
            showSection: true
          },
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('medications');
    }
  ]);
}());
```

Click your buttons `medication` and `medication add` to see the value change.

Comment: I like this approach. I liked the last one as well you did, but the issue there was that I kept getting a error that the `showSection` could not be set when going to other `states`, even though I wasn't using any `sub-state` or the `mainController`. I'll give this a try.

Comment: is the code exactly the same or is there other code you aren't showing us? what is the error?

Comment: Nevermind, my misstake, it works. I just want to test one thing and maybe ask a follow up question if ok?

Answer (score 1):

The callback of $stateChangeSuccess, you have access toState, fromState. Or check current state name

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
          if ($state.current.name == "medications.add") {

             $scope.openSesame = true;
          } 

          console.log($scope.openSesame);
});
```

Comment: ok so this works. But is this normal approach or more of a workaround? I mean I have to add both routes there `==='medcations'` and `==='medications.add'`

Comment: And, what is the point of sending params for me in this case? when do you actually use the params, for other cases I mean.

Comment: 1st: normal approach would be having its own controller for the sub-state. That way you won't need this $stateChangeSuccess watch 2nd: don't pass the  params if you don't need